# How to filter out models with null properties in Yii2

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2, relationship

In my application I have product entities with related translation (description in different languages), accessories (a list of products) and finally price entity. There is Euro price-list, Dollar, Australian and proper the price entry is retrieved by using current price-list id.

```
class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    ...

    public function getPrice()
    {
        $supplier = Supplier::getCurrent();
        return $this->hasOne(ProductPrice::className(), ['IDProduct' => 'IDProduct'])
                    ->onCondition(['PriceListID' => ... getCurrentPricelistID()]);
    }
    ...
}
```

The query below retrieves an array of product entries with populated price, accessories and translation properties.

```
$query = Product::find()
   ->where($conditions)
   ->with('translation', 'accessories', 'price')
   ->asArray()
   ->all();
```

I need to filter out product entries with null prices. So that some price-lists, for example Australian one, will have less products than the others have, because some products are not sold in that country. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with using `innerJoinWith` for price property/relation:

```
$query = Product::find() 
    ->with('translation', 'accessories')
    ->innerJoinWith('price')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

try with  this where clause:

```
$query = Product::find()
->where($conditions)
->with('translation', 'accessories', 'price')
->where(['not', ['price' => null]])
->asArray()
->all();
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work since it tries to concatenate that condition in SQL
Undefined column: 7 ERRORE: the column "price" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "tbl_products" WHERE NOT ("price" IS NULL)

Comment: sorry how are name the column?

Comment: it's `ProductPrice` (`tbl_pricelists.ProductPrice`), but it doesn't work either.
Because the output of find etc statement is just 
SELECT * FROM "tbl_products" without any sign of join, so by putting any field to where you will the query. Anyway I've just found the solution.

Comment: @salaros Why did you change a non-working solution to another non-working?

Comment: In Yii2 you can define model properties by using DB relations (via get accessors).Usually they are represented by one model or an collection. In my original query fetching all the products and then lazy-populating (I suppose that asArray is a trigger) their properties.The resulting query for each relation is LEFT JOIN-based (I suppose), that's why I got empty properties
In my answer below I used INNER JOIN relation with pre-populates price property on each model (again it's my supposition) + filters out the entries with that prop set to null,'cause this is the way how INNER JOIN relation works